# Accessing URL Helpers in Rails RSpec Mailer Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara

I'm new to Rspec, Capybara and Rails. I'm trying to run a basic mailer test using Rails 3.1. I'm basically following Railscast #275 where Ryan references a url helper as I'm doing here except for him, it works.

`spec/mailer/user_mailer_spec.rb` looks like:

```
describe UserMailer do
  it 'should have access to URL helpers' do
    lambda { password_resets_path }.should_not raise_error
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to like the URL helpers I'm using. The given error is:

```
Timothys-MacBook-Pro:onelist-rails-3.1 tim$ rspec spec
F....

Failures:

  1) UserMailer should have access to URL helpers
     Failure/Error: lambda { password_resets_path }.should_not raise_error
       expected no Exception, got #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `password_resets_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fa004697390>>
     # ./spec/mailer/user_mailer_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.31 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/mailer/user_mailer_spec.rb:18 # UserMailer should have access to URL helpers
```

The pertinent routes look like this:

```
Timothys-MacBook-Pro:onelist-rails-3.1 tim$ rake routes | grep password
    password_resets GET    /password_resets(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                    POST   /password_resets(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"password_resets"}
 new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"password_resets"}
edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets"}
     password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                    PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                    DELETE /password_resets/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"password_resets"}
```

If it's of any use, my `spec/spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'           
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include(MailerMacros)
  config.before(:each) { reset_email }
end
```

I also have this line in my `config/environments/test.rb`

```
# Set URLs to work properly in email
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "www.example.com" }
```

Comment: I just ran your test on one of my mailers and it worked fine.  Please can you create a sample app with the error and put it on github and I'll take a look.

Comment: Sure. It's actually open source for the moment anyway. https://github.com/TimFletcher/OneListRails

Comment: So I actually set up and ran Ryan's Railscast #275 and the tests passed fine. It seems something specific to my project.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it. The folder containing my mailer tests was named `mailer` rather than `mailers`. I'll put this as a proper answer when  SO lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Rspec to autoload the URL helpers, you need to ensure the folder containing your mailer is called `mailers` rather than `mailer`.